# Injecting service to parent class

Tags: angular

Is it possible to inject services into parent class?
I've got two classes. One parent class and ex. IncomeService which extends parent.

Parent:

```
@Injectable()
export class ObjectService {
    constructor(protected apiService: ApiService,
                protected cacheService: CacheService) {
    }
}
```

IncomeService

```
@Injectable()
export class IncomeService extends ObjectService {
    test() {
        this.apiService; //is undefined
    }
}
```

I want to inject servcies to parent since every child will use those services and are used in parent class. As I see angular is not injecting `apiService` and `cacheService` to IncomeService.
Is it a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is basically no other way than to repeat the constructor parameters in the subclass and pass it to the superclass using the `super(...)` call.

```
@Injectable()
export class IncomeService extends ObjectService {
    constructor(protected apiService: ApiService,
                protected cacheService: CacheService) {
      super(apiService, cacheService);
    }
    test() {
        this.apiService; //is undefined
    }
}
```

There are answers with some ugly hacks to work around this but I'd discourage.

Comment: It works, but needs a lot of code - oh well... Thanks

Comment: Yes it's a bit of boilerplate, but the constructor design is this way because sane object initialization is complicated.

Comment: @MuzaffarMahmood as far as I know it is not necessary to repeat the constructor parameters in subclasses anymore since quite some time. If there is no constructor in the subclass, the constructor of the superclass takes effect. This answer is outdated.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ok. I am getting very strange error. I am extending two classes(Angular components) from one parent class(Angular component) and in one derived class it is working fine without constructor but not in other. Very strange.

Comment: @MuzaffarMahmood that's not enough details. I'd suggest to create a new question with full (but minimal) reproduction